# Simple bootstrap form building

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I need help building a simple form. I have the form all set up and "working" based on the bootstrap docs. Here is my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
<!-- Form Name -->

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surgical skils">Do you have surgical skills?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="surgical skils-0">
      <input type="radio" name="surgical skils" id="surgical skils-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Yes
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="surgical skils-1">
      <input type="radio" name="surgical skils" id="surgical skils-1" value="2">
      No
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="manipulation skills">Do you have sperm and embryo manipulation skills?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="manipulation skills-0">
      <input type="radio" name="manipulation skills" id="manipulation skills-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Yes
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="manipulation skills-1">
      <input type="radio" name="manipulation skills" id="manipulation skills-1" value="2">
      No
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="freezers">Do you have access to liquid nitrogen and liquid nitrogen freezers?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="freezers-0">
      <input type="radio" name="freezers" id="freezers-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Yes
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="freezers-1">
      <input type="radio" name="freezers" id="freezers-1" value="2">
      No
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="history">Have you had success with previous attempts to cryo preserve sperm?</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="history-0">
      <input type="radio" name="history" id="history-0" value="1" checked="checked">
      Yes
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="history-1">
      <input type="radio" name="history" id="history-1" value="2">
      No
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

My question and confusion is related to the submit button. Upon submission, I want the form area to display text based on the answers. In other words, I want the form to look at the questions and for any 'no' responses - display this message. Otherwise if they're all 'yes' then display this message.

The form data does not need to be saved nor does it need to be sent anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you use javascript for this?

Comment: Run JavaScript function on form submit. Return false for no responses and show alerts. <form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit = "return myValidationFunction();">

Comment: Good suggestion! The problem is that I'm not a javascript programmer. What would that script look like?

Comment: You have included [`jQuery`](https://api.jquery.com/) in the tags, Have you tried to achieve your goal using it? Or you're about to ask - *"please write the code for me"* ?

Comment: no not asking anyone to "write the code for me" - just need a little direction BUT that said here is what I tried. 
   `<script>
    function validateForm()   {
    // validation fails if the input is no
    if(form.surgicalskills.value == "2") {
      alert("You need our help");
      return false;
    }
   </script>`

The question remains, do I need to do this for all for fields? Or can I create a blank rule for the entire form if any 'no' responses, then show this text - if else (all are 'yes') show this text?

Comment: @timrosenthal is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/ray716/vnsxmwjz/

Comment: That's close to what I need but is there way for the alert to not be a pop-up?

Comment: here is the latest one that I developed - just wanted to see if I could get the fields to validate if blank. but now i need to know how to run a validation on a value. https://jsfiddle.net/timrosenthal/fm6fqbss/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some critical thinking last night, I figured this out.

```
$("#cryo-kit .cryo-submit").on("click",function(){
        var no = 0, yes = 0, total = 0;
    $('#cryo-kit .radio-wrapper').each(function(index, node){
        total += 1;
        var checkedValue = $(this).find("input:checked").val();
        if(checkedValue == 'no'){ no += 1;}
      if(checkedValue == 'yes'){ yes += 1;}
    }).promise().done(function(){
        if(no == total){
        $("#cryo-form-result").text("I don't think you're qualified, contact us");
      } else if (yes == total) {
        $("#cryo-form-result").text("Congrats! You can buy our kit");
      } else {
        $("#cryo-form-result").text("I don't think you're qualified, contact us");
      }
    });
});
```